# How to traverse a linked list using java's linked list class if I don't have access the node structer

Tags: java, linked-list

So I have created a linked list using javas linked list class but what I don't understand is when adding new items or traversing though the list how do get the reference to each node? Does java have a method for that?I understand how I would do that if I were to create my own linked list and node structure but I don't understand how it works using javas LinkedList class. This has been marked as a duplicate but the other questions asked that are like this don't clearly answer the question

Comment: Look at both the Java API and the source code, and see for yourself.

Comment: I have been reading this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) but I still don't understand